# No Adapter Attached Skipping layout error with RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

These are steps I am doing in this project:

- First I am creating a user profile on Firebase
- Once the profile is created, I am redirecting the user to another activity, where the user is creating a journal with Image
- Then saving the journal with image on Firestore
- Once the data is created on the user profile, I am trying to fetch the values from Firestore using RecyclerView Adapter
- Then on a listing page I am trying to fetch all the values in an ArrayList--> **here I am getting the error of No Adapter Attached**

**The ArrayList Activity file:**

- Initializing the recyclerView in OnCreate

  ```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_journal_list);

        firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user= firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        noJournalEntry= findViewById(R.id.list_no_thoughts);
        journalList= new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    }
  ```
- Invoking the RecyclerView in onStart:

  ```
   @Override
   protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       //we are getting the user Id of the person who is logged in
       collectionReference.whereEqualTo("userId", JournalApi.getInstance()
               .getUserId())
               .get()
               .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
               if(!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                   for(QueryDocumentSnapshot journals: queryDocumentSnapshots){
                       Journal journal = journals.toObject(Journal.class);
                       journalList.add(journal);

                      Toast.makeText(JournalListActivity.this,"UserId found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }

                   // Invoke Recyclerview

                   journalRecyclerAdapter= new JournalRecyclerAdapter(JournalListActivity.this, journalList);
                   recyclerView.setAdapter(journalRecyclerAdapter);
                   journalRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

               } else {

                   noJournalEntry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

               }
           }
       }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

               Toast.makeText(JournalListActivity.this,"UserId NOT found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           }
       });


   }
  ```

  }

As you can see that the RecyclerView is called fine, but the ArrayList is not loading.

The **Error**:  `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`

I referred to various posts in Stackoverflow and followed the steps, not sure where I am going wrong.

I am adding screenshots here of the Arraylist file:
[image]

The RecyclerView adapter:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **500 (five hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Thank you @AlexMamo I am new to Stackoverflow, hence my intent was to give all the context so that people aware what I was trying to do. I have updated my post, I hope you could help me.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following warning, not an error:

> E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Because you are setting the adapter in a background thread. To solve this, you have to set the adapter **outside** the callback and inside it, just notify it about the changes. So please **move** the following lines of code:

```
journalRecyclerAdapter= new JournalRecyclerAdapter(JournalListActivity.this, journalist);
recyclerView.setAdapter(journalRecyclerAdapter);
```

Right after:

```
super.onStart();
```

And leave the following line as it is inside the callback:

```
journalRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And the warning will disapear.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I moved the code snippet as mentioned and the error is gone. However my Arraylist is still not loading in file, anything else I should be looking for?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot, to see how it looks like.

Comment: I have added the screenshots as well Alex. I feel this seems to be some issue with the AndroidX and recycler view compatibility. However when I changed to Android V7, it worked.