# Could not deserialize object.Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.quiz.models.Question (found in field 'questions.title')

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from Firestore. But the error occurs:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.quiz.models.Question (found in field 'questions.title')

The error is found in setUpFirestore() and because of the line: Log.d("DATA", value.toObjects(Quiz::class.java).toString()) {as per logcat error}

My MainActivity:

```
    package com.example.quiz.activities

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.example.quiz.R
import com.example.quiz.adapters.QuizAdapter
import com.example.quiz.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.quiz.models.Quiz
import com.google.android.material.datepicker.MaterialDatePicker
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var actionBarDrawerToggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle
    lateinit var adapter: QuizAdapter
    private var quizList = mutableListOf<Quiz>()
    lateinit var firestore : FirebaseFirestore

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setUpViews()
    }

    fun setUpViews(){
        setUpFirestore()
        setUpDrawerLayout()
        setUpRecyclerView()
        setUpDatePicker()
    }

    private fun setUpDatePicker() {
        val btnDatePicker = binding.btnDatePicker
        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener{
            val datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().build()
            datePicker.show(supportFragmentManager,"DatePicker")
            datePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
                Log.d("DATEPICKER",datePicker.headerText)
                val dateFormatter =  SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy")
                val date = dateFormatter.format(Date(it))
                val intent = Intent(this,QuestionActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("DATE",date)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            datePicker.addOnNegativeButtonClickListener {
                Log.d("DATEPICKER",datePicker.headerText)
            }
            datePicker.addOnCancelListener {
                Log.d("DATEPICKER","Date Picker was cancelled")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setUpFirestore() {
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val collectionReference = firestore.collection("quizzes")
        collectionReference.addSnapshotListener{ value,error ->
            if(value == null || error != null){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Error fetching data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            Log.d("DATA", value.toObjects(Quiz::class.java).toString())
            quizList.clear()
            quizList.addAll(value.toObjects(Quiz::class.java))
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView(){
        val quizRecyclerView = binding.quizRecyclerView
        adapter = QuizAdapter(this,quizList)
        quizRecyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,2)
        quizRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    fun setUpDrawerLayout(){
        val appBar = binding.appBar
        val mainDrawer = binding.mainDrawer
        val navigationView = binding.navigationView
        setSupportActionBar(appBar)
        actionBarDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mainDrawer,
            R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name
        )
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            val intent = Intent(this,ProfileActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            mainDrawer.closeDrawers()
            true
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

my Question model is mentioned below:

```
package com.example.quiz.models

data class Question(
    var description: String = "",
    var option1: String = "",
    var option2: String = "",
    var option3: String = "",
    var option4: String = "",
    var answer: String = "",
    var userAnswer:String=""
)
```

my quiz model is -

```
package com.example.quiz.models

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

data class Quiz(
    var id: String = "",
    var title: String = "",
    var questions: MutableMap<String, Question> = mutableMapOf()
)
```

database image:

[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEQIe.png)

logcat error is -

```
2022-04-24 17:19:04.678 12341-12341/com.example.quiz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.quiz, PID: 12341
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.quiz.models.Question (found in field 'questions.title')
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeError(CustomClassMapper.java:568)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:549)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:258)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:194)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToParameterizedType(CustomClassMapper.java:296)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:192)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$300(CustomClassMapper.java:57)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:775)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:746)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:547)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:258)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:103)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(DocumentSnapshot.java:183)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(QueryDocumentSnapshot.java:116)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.toObjects(QuerySnapshot.java:184)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.toObjects(QuerySnapshot.java:166)
        at com.example.quiz.activities.MainActivity.setUpFirestore$lambda-4(MainActivity.kt:95)
        at com.example.quiz.activities.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$ALF8Ugv5XcVyBlrGHEr70w5PaxM(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.quiz.activities.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.onEvent(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2$com-google-firebase-firestore-Query(Query.java:1205)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0$com-google-firebase-firestore-core-AsyncEventListener(AsyncEventListener.java:42)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: added the database image

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: The error is found in setUpFirestore(), because of the line: Log.d("DATA", value.toObjects(Quiz::class.java).toString())

Comment: I see now. I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the following error:

> Could not deserialize object.Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.quiz.models.Question (found in field 'questions.title')

Because when using this line of code:

```
Log.d("DATA", value.toObjects(Quiz::class.java).toString())
```

It means that you're trying to convert each document into an object of type `Quiz`, which is actually not possible. Why? Because each document should contain a `questions` array which should be composed of **only** `Question` objects. But this is not happening since that array contains also a String called title. As I see in your Quiz class, the title field should be a field directly within the document and should **not** be present inside the array. To solve this, you have to remove the title from the array and add it as a field inside the document.

Comment: : ) The firebase issue has been solved, but one error I am getting : E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: It's most likely because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69459717/no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout-error-with-recyclerview-adapter/69565524#69565524).

Comment: Please check this :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72028142/questions-are-not-getting-fetched-when-using-floating-action-button

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.