# Questions are not getting fetched when using floating action button

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I am making a quiz app. My main activity has blocks. Each block has a date written over it. the date act as title while fetching information from firebase. These blocks are working perfectly fine, (fetching questions).I also have a floating action button, on clicking displays a calender and we can select date from there and access quiz for that particular day, but it is not working .

Home screen : [home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU0sh.png)

Interface while accessing question from block : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbxop.png)

Interface while accessing through floating action bar :[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECQa1.png)

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.quiz.activities

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.example.quiz.R
import com.example.quiz.adapters.QuizAdapter
import com.example.quiz.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.quiz.models.Quiz
import com.google.android.material.datepicker.MaterialDatePicker
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    lateinit var actionBarDrawerToggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle
    lateinit var adapter: QuizAdapter
    private var quizList = mutableListOf<Quiz>()
    lateinit var firestore : FirebaseFirestore

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setUpViews()
    }

    fun setUpViews(){
        setUpFirestore()
        setUpDrawerLayout()
        setUpRecyclerView()
        setUpDatePicker()
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private fun setUpDatePicker() {
//        val btnDatePicker = binding.btnDatePicker
        binding.btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener{
            val datePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker().build()
            datePicker.show(supportFragmentManager,"DatePicker")
            datePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
                Log.d("DATEPICKER",datePicker.headerText)
                val dateFormatter =  SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy")
                val date = dateFormatter.format(Date(it))
                val intent = Intent(this,QuestionActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("DATE",date)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            datePicker.addOnNegativeButtonClickListener {
                Log.d("DATEPICKER",datePicker.headerText)
            }
            datePicker.addOnCancelListener {
                Log.d("DATEPICKER","Date Picker was cancelled")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setUpFirestore() {
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val collectionReference = firestore.collection("quizzes")
        collectionReference.addSnapshotListener{ value, error ->
            if(value == null || error != null){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Error fetching data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            Log.d("DATA", value.toObjects(Quiz::class.java).toString())
            quizList.clear()
            quizList.addAll(value.toObjects(Quiz::class.java))
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView(){
        val quizRecyclerView = binding.quizRecyclerView
        adapter = QuizAdapter(this,quizList)
        quizRecyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this,2)
        quizRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun setUpDrawerLayout(){
        val appBar = binding.appBar
        val mainDrawer = binding.mainDrawer
        val navigationView = binding.navigationView
        setSupportActionBar(appBar)
        actionBarDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mainDrawer,
            R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name
        )
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            val intent = Intent(this,ProfileActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            mainDrawer.closeDrawers()
            true
        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Quiz adapter

```
package com.example.quiz.adapters

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.quiz.R
import com.example.quiz.activities.QuestionActivity
import com.example.quiz.models.Quiz
import com.example.quiz.utils.ColorPicker
import com.example.quiz.utils.IconPicker


class QuizAdapter(val context: Context, val quizzes: List<Quiz>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<QuizAdapter.QuizViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): QuizViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.quiz_item,parent,false)
        return QuizViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: QuizViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textViewTitle.text = quizzes[position].title
        holder.cardContainer.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(ColorPicker.getColor()))
        holder.iconView.setImageResource(IconPicker.getIcon())
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(context,quizzes[position].title,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(context , QuestionActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("DATE",quizzes[position].title)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return quizzes.size
    }

    inner class QuizViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var textViewTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quizTitle)
        var iconView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quizIcon)
        var cardContainer: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardContainer)
    }
}
```

Question Activity

```
package com.example.quiz.activities

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.view.allViews
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.quiz.R
import com.example.quiz.adapters.OptionAdapter
import com.example.quiz.databinding.ActivityQuestionBinding
import com.example.quiz.models.Question
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.example.quiz.models.Quiz
import com.google.gson.Gson


class QuestionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var quizzes : MutableList<Quiz>? = null
    var questions : MutableMap<String,Question>? = null
    var index = 1

    lateinit var firestore : FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityQuestionBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityQuestionBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setUpFireStore()
        setUpEventListener()
    }

    private fun setUpEventListener() {
        val btnPrevious = binding.btnPrevious
        val btnSubmit = binding.btnSubmit
        val btnNext = binding.btnNext
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener{
            index--
            bindViews()
        }
         btnNext.setOnClickListener{
            index++
            bindViews()
        }
         btnSubmit.setOnClickListener{
            Log.d("FINAL QUIZ",questions.toString())
             val intent = Intent(this,ResultActivity::class.java)
             val json = Gson().toJson(quizzes!![0])
             intent.putExtra("QUIZ",json)
             startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    private fun setUpFireStore() {
        val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        var date = intent.getStringExtra("DATE")
        if (date!= null){
            firestore.collection("quizzes").whereEqualTo("title",date)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    if (it != null && !it.isEmpty){
                        Log.d("DATA",it.toObjects(Quiz::class.java).toString())
                        quizzes = it.toObjects(Quiz::class.java)
                        questions = quizzes!![0].questions
                        bindViews()
                }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Error Fetching data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun bindViews() {
        val btnPrevious = binding.btnPrevious
        val btnSubmit = binding.btnSubmit
        val btnNext = binding.btnNext
        val description = binding.description
        val optionList = binding.optionList

        btnPrevious.visibility = View.GONE
        btnSubmit.visibility = View.GONE
        btnNext.visibility = View.GONE

        if (index == 1) {
            btnNext.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        else if(index == questions!!.size){
            btnSubmit.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            btnPrevious.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        else{
            btnNext.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            btnPrevious.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        val question = questions!!["question$index"]
        question?.let {
            description.text = it.description
            val optionAdapter = OptionAdapter(this,it)
            optionList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            optionList.adapter = optionAdapter
            optionList.setHasFixedSize(true)
        }
    }
}
```

No logcat error is shown but this error is shown in run section : E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Everything seems correct, have you tried logging-in the date you're sending from the date picker? Is it same as Firestore query requires? Because as it seems, your Firestore query to fetch the questions works perfect, it just results in no data as there's none for the date you're trying to fetch for.

Comment: I've tried it .

Comment: And what is it?