# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout and Firestore Permission Denied

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am getting some errors while writing an ecommerce app. Where is the issue that causing this errors.

**The errors:**

E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: GooglePlayServices not available due to error 9
W/Firestore: (24.6.1) [GrpcCallProvider]: Failed to update ssl context: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
I/TetheringManager: registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.farmershop
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
W/Firestore: (24.6.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(PopularProducts order by **name**);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

**The codes I used:**
**PopularAdapter.java:**

```
public class PopularAdapters extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PopularAdapters.ViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<PopularModel> popularModelList;

    public PopularAdapters(Context context, List<PopularModel> popularModelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.popularModelList = popularModelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.popular_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Glide.with(context).load(popularModelList.get(position).getImg_url()).into(holder.popImg);
        holder.name.setText(popularModelList.get(position).getName());
        holder.rating.setText(popularModelList.get(position).getRating());
        holder.description.setText(popularModelList.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.discount.setText(popularModelList.get(position).getDiscount());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        try {
            return popularModelList.size();
        } catch (Exception ex){return 0;}
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView popImg;
        TextView name,description,rating,discount;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            popImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pop_img);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pop_name);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pop_des);
            rating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pop_rating);
            discount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pop_discount);

        }
    }
}
```

**HomeFragment.java:**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView popularRec;
    FirebaseFirestore db;

//popular items
    List<PopularModel> popularModelList;
    PopularAdapters popularAdapters;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        popularRec = root.findViewById(R.id.pop_rec);

        //popular items
        popularRec.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false));
        popularModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        popularAdapters = new PopularAdapters(getActivity(),popularModelList);
        popularRec.setAdapter(popularAdapters);

        db.collection("PopularProducts")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                PopularModel popularModel = document.toObject(PopularModel.class);
                                popularModelList.add(popularModel);
                                popularAdapters.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error"+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        return root;

    }
}
```

**Firebase Code:**

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to implement the layoutmanager in the xml but that didn't work for me. Still getting the errors.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69459717/no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout-error-with-recyclerview-adapter/69565524#69565524) will help.

Answer (score 0):

The security rules in your question are for Cloud Storage, a service for storing files.

The error message in your question is from Cloud Firestore, a document database.

While both are part of Firebase, they are separate services that have little to do with each other. The rules for Storage don't apply to Firestore, and vice versa.

I recommend reading the documentation on [getting started with  Firestore's security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started), and the ones about all [products that have security rules in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started)